# Adding Database Backup & Restore function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm making a project in C #. I'm using sql database in my project. I want to put into the project data base backup and restore function. What things I have to do/code for it?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/restore-sql-server-backup-file-with-C-Sharp/

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to backup the complete database, or do you only want to be able to restore to the state before you changed the database?

The first is quite uncommon to do this from within your program, after all: are you sure that no one else is changing the database while you are backing up?

The latter is quite common: Before you make several changes to the database you remember how it was before the change, do the changes, and decide whether you want to keep the changes or go back to the situation before you changed it, for instance because of errors.

This latter is done using the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction class.

```
using (var sqlConnection = GetSqlConnection(...))
{
    try (sqlConnection.Open()
    {   // before making the changes: remember the state of the database
        using (var transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            bool changesOk = true;
            try
            {
                changesOk = ChangeDatabase(...);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                changesOk = false;
            }

            if (!changesOk)
            {   // go back to the state at the beginning of the transaction
                transaction.RollBack();
            }
            else
            {   // no error: save the changes:
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to backup complete database and restore it.

Answer (score 0):

**[**Backup and Restore SQL Server databases programmatically with SMO](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/)****

SMO provides utility classes for specific tasks. For backup and restore, it provides two main utility classes (Backup and Restore) which are available in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo namespace.

This is sample code.

```
 Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
    /* Specify whether you want to back up database or files or log */
    bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    /* Specify the name of the database to back up */
    bkpDBFull.Database = myDatabase.Name;
    /* You can take backup on several media type (disk or tape), here I am
     * using File type and storing backup on the file system */
    bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\AdventureWorksFull.bak", DeviceType.File);
    bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Adventureworks database Backup";
    bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Adventureworks database - Full Backup";
    /* You can specify the expiration date for your backup data
     * after that date backup data would not be relevant */
    bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);

    /* You can specify Initialize = false (default) to create a new 
     * backup set which will be appended as last backup set on the media. You
     * can specify Initialize = true to make the backup as first set on the
     * medium and to overwrite any other existing backup sets if the all the
     * backup sets have expired and specified backup set name matches with
     * the name on the medium */
    bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

    /* Wiring up events for progress monitoring */
    bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
    bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

    /* SqlBackup method starts to take back up
     * You can also use SqlBackupAsync method to perform the backup 
     * operation asynchronously */
    bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);
    private static void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", args.Percent);
    }
    private static void Backup_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Backup completed." );
        Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
    }
    private static void Restore_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Restore completed.");
        Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
    }
```